# AzureAD signout error mesage: "Hmm... we're having trouble signing you out."

Tags: asp.net, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I created a web application using ASP.NET CORE, using the quickstart guide in the AzureAD portal. Signing in works, but when I attempt to log out, after about 5 seconds, I get the following message:

https://i.imgur.com/RhOGaf6.png

My app has been registered with the following redirect URIs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfJ7T.png

With https://localhost:52410/signout-oidc as logout URL, and implicit grand for ID tokens enabled.

I can see in the browser debug menu under network that there is no response 
from the logout URL. So, I'm assuming that the error message pop ups because the logout URL takes too long to respond.

Note: If I reload the browser page with the error I **do** logout.

So I'm wondering how can I resolve this error message?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, please edit your question and replace the images by error text, see this article : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors . Also please take a look at this help article before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you check my article: https://joonasw.net/view/aad-single-sign-out-in-asp-net-core?

Comment: For example, SameSite=lax will prevent single sign out from working if it's set on the auth cookie. And it is set by default in newer versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this error by adjusting the launchSettings.json file.

I adjusted the iisExpress setting in iisSettings to use SSL like so:

```
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3110/",
  "sslPort": 44321
}
```

On top of this, I adjusted the port of my own application to also use 3110.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the configurations are fine. Here is an working sample for your reference. You can check the code for signing out.

```
[\[HttpGet\]
        public IActionResult SignOut()
        {
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(SignedOut), "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
            return SignOut(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        \[HttpGet\]
        public IActionResult SignedOut()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // Redirect to home page if the user is authenticated.
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
            }

            return View();
        }][1]
```